# Where can I drill onto exterior walls of the house and detached garage for installing the heavier patio string lights

Tags: lighting, drill, exterior, patio

I am a new home owner and not really aware if I would cause long term damage by drilling any where I feel like. So I am seeking help from the forum. Highly appreciate all the help !

The lights will be in a triangular fashion, hanging at two points from the exterior of the house and at one point in the detached garage. The detached garage is not higher ground.
I have labelled points 1 on the garage, and 2 and 3 on point where the wall and the ceiling of the tiny porch like extension of the house meet.

[image: Here is the blue print of how the lights are to be hung]

1. For point 1 on the garage, I see the long strip of wood beside the gutter as an option, but it's thin enough so that the fish eye will pass it and then get inserted in the siding too. I am not sure if this is the only option. What do you guys think ? Another option is the fascia board, but that is too high for my purposes.

[image: Options for Point 1 on the garage]

2. For points 2 and 3 - there is piece of wood that projects just below the ceiling (Marked with a Black Rectangle) in this image. I think that is big enough for a larger fish eye screw, but I am not sure if that's cause any damage. Only other option for these two points is the siding.

[image: Options for points 2 and 3]

I have tried looking for forums and have spoken to people in HomeDepot etc but haven't gotten a decent answer. So I will appreciate any help that I can get.

Answer (score 1):

You can put them roughly where you have marked them. You can get probably 1/4" eye bolts about 3" long, preferably stainless. Behind the trim on the corners 1 & 3 are at least 2x4 used in framing and #2 has a rafter close to that point, you will probably need a stud finder to locate it. These would be available at your favorite box store. Locations 1 & 2 are close to an electrical source so that should go fairly easy.

Comment: Thanks @Gil. I have a stud finder from Costco. Just so that I understand, you are saying and 1 and 3 have solid wood due to the framing and that I need to find a solid point for 2 by using a stud finder (the rafter) ?

Comment: Bingo! You are right on:-)

Comment: Well the stud finder is inconclusive in finding the rafter. It blinks sometimes and doesn't the other times. Is it safe to drill where a stud seems to be meeting the ceiling ?

Comment: Can you try a different stud finder first? If that fails try drilling a very small hole maybe 1/16" about 2" from the corner and see if you hit solid wood, I would be surprised if you don't. That would work for 1 & 3. Maybe move #2 to the left on the corner. 1 would be wood and behind it is the framing probably 2x4. Let me know how this works out.